# How to send TCP packets from one host to another in mininet by using a python script?

Tags: python, mininet, pox

I am new to mininet. I created a topology in mininet and want to write a python code which can help me to send 100 TCP packets from one host to another.

any idea please?

Comment: https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet#working

Answer (score 1):

You can send TCP packets from one host to another using a tool such as `iperf` or `hping`. For example, type the following command in the Mininet console:

```
mininet> h1 hping3 -c 100 [IP_of_h2]
```

Option `-c` specifies the number of TCP packets that will be sent. You can see more options for `hping3` [here](http://0daysecurity.com/articles/hping3_examples.html).

Comment: In fact I want to create a ddos attack on topology using scapy. I write a .py script for this. The problem is that I have no idea how to call each hosts in my custom topology and run attack.py (ddos attack script).